# Pulling table values into case expression per parts of table

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a complex query, that will eventually have an output of this:

Table A:

| Job Number | Process Step A | Process Step B | Process Step C |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Job A | Waiting | Completed | Waiting |
| Job B | In Process | Completed | Waiting |
| Job C | Completed | Waiting | Waiting |

I have a subquery table left joined that has the LAST Transaction for each of these jobs at each of these steps, that looks like this:

Table B:

| Job Number | Process Step | Status |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Job A | Process Step A | Waiting |
| Job A | Process Step B | Completed |
| Job A | Process Step C | Waiting |
| Job B | Process Step A | In Process |
| Job B | Process Step B | Completed |
| Job B | Process Step C | Waiting |
| Job C | Process Step A | Completed |
| Job C | Process Step B | Waiting |
| Job C | Process Step C | Waiting |

I'm trying to do a case statement that basically says "If you find the status of Process Step A on Table B matching Table A's Job Number and column name, then use that Status, else show 'N/A'"

Here is the code (this is a small part of the whole thing):

```
SELECT CASE 
            WHEN SOI.[ValueStream] = '2D' or SOI.[ValueStream] = 'TS' THEN '2D/TS'
            ELSE '3D' 
            END AS [VS],
        CASE 
            WHEN Holds.[HoldSteps] like '%Pouch Pulling%' THEN 'Hold' 
            WHEN SOI.[Pouch Pulling Time] = 0 THEN 'N/A' 
            WHEN --Problem to build code here 
            ELSE 'Waiting' 
            END AS [PPStat]
FROM 
(
SELECT A.[Job Number], A.[Product], A.[Quantity], A.[Release Week] 
    FROM [Job Planning Info] AS A 
    WHERE A.[Released] = 'Yes'
UNION ALL 
    SELECT B.[Remake Job Number], A.[Product], B.[Remake Quantity], A.[Release Week] 
    FROM [Remake Tracker] AS B
INNER JOIN 
    [Job Planning Info] AS A ON A.[Job Number] = B.[Original Job Number]  
    WHERE A.[Release Week] is not null
) AS JobList

LEFT JOIN
(
    SELECT [Job Number], STRING_AGG(CAST([Process Step] as NVARCHAR(MAX)), ',') AS HoldSteps 
    FROM [Hold Tracker] 
    GROUP BY [Job Number]
) AS Holds 
ON JobList.[Job Number] = Holds.[Job Number]

LEFT JOIN [Second Ops Info] AS SOI 
        ON Joblist.[Product] = SOI.[Part Number]

LEFT JOIN 
(
    SELECT DISTINCT JTL.[Job Number], JTL.[Process Step], 
    CASE 
        WHEN JTL.[Transaction Type] like '%Start Job%' THEN 'IP' 
        WHEN JTL.[Transaction Type] like '%Job Completed%' THEN 'Completed' 
        ELSE 'Waiting' 
        END AS [TranslatedStat] 
    FROM [Job Transaction List] JTL
    WHERE JTL.[Job Number] <> '' and JTL.[TimeStamp] >= DATEADD(Month, -1, GETDATE())
    and JTL.[TimeStamp] = 
        (
            SELECT MAX(JTL2.[TimeStamp]) 
            FROM [Job Transaction List] JTL2 
            WHERE JTL.[Job Number] = JTL2.[Job Number] and JTL.[Process Step] = JTL2.[Process Step]
        ) 
    ORDER BY JTL.[Job Number], JTL.[Process Step]
) AS ProcStepStats 
ON JobList.[Job Number] = ProcStepStats.[Job Number]

LEFT JOIN [Live Schedule Automatic Pull] AS LSAP 
    ON JobList.[Job Number] = LSAP.[Job Number]
```

I was thinking of not sharing the code, but it probably makes more sense with it in there even though it's a lot more information in the code than what I'm actually asking for here.

Any help appreciated.

Comment: Fixed to match case as an expression not a statement.

Comment: It is just not helpful for your text to refer to "Table A" and "Table B" while your code refers to very different names. After multiple readings, what you label as "Table A" if first defined as an "output" - adding confusion about whether your first formatted block is an actual table or a resultset of some query or process. And it would help to see a "N/A" situation in your sample data. Lastly, distill your question into a [MVCE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). It seems much of your code is not relevant to the question.